# Vectorize curve fitting data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, curve-fitting

I want to speed up a process on a dataframe where every row in the dataframe are points (red points in the image), and I fit every row to a polynomial (blue points in the image):

[image: graphic]

My dataframe would look like this one:

```
0   21.357071   21.357071   NaN     29.240519   20.909416   23.884323   NaN     NaN     21.533360   19.145000   NaN
1   29.373487   29.373487   NaN     32.593994   26.423960   29.623251   NaN     NaN     30.685534   29.297455   20.411913
2   19.116655   19.116655   NaN     27.120478   18.723265   19.857676   NaN     NaN     20.249647   18.867172   NaN
```

I already did this with the following code:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  dataR = row[:].dropna()

  x = np.array(dataR.index).astype(float) #x = column index
  y = dataR.values
  y = np.vstack(y).astype(np.float).T[0]  #y = value

  coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, deg=4)
  ffit = poly.polyval(np.arange(0,maxColumns,1), coefs)
  df.loc[index,0:maxColumns] = ffit
```

But my dataframe is very big so this is slow. I wonder if I can vectorize this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you are handling each row independently and perform curve fitting not matter what other rows look like, I think you can simply parallelize the code using [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), so you can do

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

function fit_curve(row):
    dataR = row[:].dropna()
    x = np.array(dataR.index).astype(float)
    y = dataR.values
    y = np.vstack(y).astype(np.float).T[0]
    coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, deg=4)
    ffit = poly.polyval(np.arange(0,maxColumns,1), coefs)
    return ffit

fitted_curves = Parallel(n_jobs=N)(delayed(fit_curve)(row) for index, row in df.iterrows())
df.loc[:,:] = fitted_curves
```

where N is number of workers, aka. cores you want to use for this.

Comment: It is not a vectorization operation but it is very fast now like 10x faster, ty

Comment: True. 
I do not think you can vectorize the numpy curve fitting itself easily in this manner, so to really vectorize it, you would probably have to reimplement it yourself.